# What makes the gradient vector plot go up first then down?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I've got this problem in my math homework, and I'm having a really difficult time actually understanding the question it's trying to ask and therefore have been unable to actually complete the problem.

The function is $f(x,y) = 4 \cos(0.25 x y)$

The parametric function given is

$$(x(t), y(t)) = (2, 1.5) + t \, \nabla f(2, 1.5)$$

The question asked is

> The knowledge of what fact about gradients gives you the ability to predict, before seeing the plot, that the curve must go up before it can go down?

Where the plot in question is a plot of $(x(t), y(t), f(x(t), y(t))$ for $0\le t\le 3$

Can anyone figure this out and give me a bit of help finding the right direction to approach this problem?

Comment: One key concept here is "directional derivative", the rate of change of $f$ in some direction. There's a formula for it in terms of the gradient. As a consequence of that formula, the direction of gradient is shown to be the direction of steepest ascent... hence the answer.

Comment: Ah yes that makes a lot of sense now, I see how I can approach this now. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one had me pretty stumped until I started thinking about the original problem a bit more.

Basically it amounts to the following fact, the plot itself is a plot of $(t, f(x(t),y(t)))$ which means that it's going to show the height across a path through the original surface, going along the gradient vector.

So since the initial starting point is the same point as our gradient vector, the initial change will be increasing because we are following the path of the gradient vector, or greatest ascent. As we reach the other side though, the surface which is basically mirrored on both sides. This means our ascent will point the same way, but traveling along the ascent will actually desend as the path is flipped and now going down.

This explains both the original "why it must go up" and the implied "why would it then go down?"